# Bootstrap scaffolding is not working properly: span6 div goes to a new line after span6 div

Tags: grid, twitter-bootstrap-3, scaffolding

I placed two `div`s with a class `span6` withing one `div` with class `row`. But as you can see in the screenshot the second `div.span6` goes to a new line instead of float to the right of the previous `div.span6`:

[image: span6]

As you can see the width of the `div.span6` is 1130 pixels (seams like to be a full width of the parent).

Could you make clear what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of bootstrap are you using?  Since Bootstrap 3 the grid system changed, and you should use for example col-sm-6.

Here's the latest grid system documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Version is 3 as I can remember.